# accessing a variable from outside a function and returning the variable. In a module pattern

Tags: javascript, function, module, scope

I'm learning about how to split up different functionalities into different section so I could have loose coupling. i have two object 1.'addition' and 2. 'subtraction'. I don't think that info  matters for this Q. what i want to do is that when amount = 3 in the index.html file the amount shhould be passed into addition.getAmount(amount) . In is one.js I try to return that amount  `function getAmount (amount){
            return amount;
        }`

I call that function and assign it to `addAmount` `var addAmount = getAmount();`. then I return an object with a property called `returnAmount` which has the value of `addAmount` which should have the returned value from getAmount(), which in this case should be 3.

Index.html snippet

```
<script src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script >
    var clicked = "addition";
    var amount = 3;
    //var returned = true
</script>
<script src="one.js"></script>
<script src = "two.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(clicked == "addition"){
        addition.method()
        addition.getAmount(amount)
        console.log(addition.returnAmount) //should output 3
    }
    if(clicked == "subtraction"){
        subtraction.method()
    }
    console.log(addition.isaddition)
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

one.js

```
var addition = (function(){
  var addAmount = getAmount();
    function getAmount (amount){
        return amount;
    }
return {
    method : function(){
        console.log("test form addition")
    },
    getAmount : getAmount,
    // this property should return 3
    returnAmount : addAmount,
    isaddition : true
}
})()
```

**`console.log(addition.returnAmount);` doesnt give me an output of 3 it gives me undefined** I want it to output 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you module first gets executed (e.g. when you script is first parsed), `addAmount` is assigned the return value of `getAmount()` which, when you don't pass in an argument, is `undefined`. Now when you return the object from the module and assign `returnAmount` to `addAmount` - you are setting `returnAmount` to `undefined` and it will **ALWAYS**  be `undefined`.

If the module variable you are accessing is dynamically updated, you cannot use a straight accessor property to get it, you **MUST** use a method.

**EDIT**

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, so this may or may not be pertinent, but I'm going to assume you're trying to mimic private members in JS:

```
var addition = (function() {

    //private variable
    var amt;

    //private method
    function getAmount(amount) {

        //assign private variable "amt" to be the value of "amount"
        amt = amount;

        return amt;
    }

    //public methods
    return {


        method: function() {
            console.log("test form addition")
        },

        //expose private method "getAmount" via public method "getAmount"
        getAmount: getAmount,

        //expose private variable "amt" via public method "returnAmount"
        returnAmount: function() {
            return amt;
        },

        isaddition: true
    }


}());

addition.getAmount(10);
addition.returnAmount(); //returns 10
```

**EDIT #2**

If you had to do this from your module pattern:

```
return {
  ...
  amt:amt
  ...
}
```

Then `amt` would be the value assigned to `amt` when your module was executed and it would never updated. There is a small caveat, objects/arrays are dealt with by reference rather than by value so if you have something like this inside your module:

```
var amt = [];

return {
  amt:amt
}
```

and you modify (e.g. `push`,`pop`,`splice`, etc) the `amt` array (but do not create a new one) then your modifications will appear everywhere where `amt` is referenced (as long as you do not *overwrite* `amt`, but that's a matter for another question.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the variable will be dynamically updated. I was trying to use a method to access the value. but I did it wrong. what will the method look like to access the variable?

Comment: thanks for an update. I wanted something like your answer.Q: so i cant go amt : amt in the return object like the way it is for is `isaddition: true`. I could only expose the private variable through a method?